# Is it possible to export the bookmark GUIDs in a Power BI report hosted on app.powerbi.com?

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Using the API endpoint:

`GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/reports/{report_id}/pages`

I can get all of the pages in a report hosted on app.powerbi.com.

Is it possible to get all of the bookmark GUIDs as well?

The endpoint:

`GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/reports/{report_id}/bookmarks`

Does not work.

I know how to manually retrieve a bookmark GUID from the url of a Power BI report:

`https://app.powerbi.com/groups/[my group]/reports/[my report]/[my page]?experience=power-bi&bookmarkGuid=*[bookmarkGUID]*`

Where *[bookmarkGUID]* is the value I am looking for, but I would like to be able to export every bookmark in the report for storage in a database to reference dynamically.

Is it even possible to export the bookmark GUIDs from a report?

Comment: You can try below methos as a workaround.  Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

There is no Endpoint to get the all the bookmarks from the report.

But if the report is embedded, then we have API `await report.bookmarksManager.getBookmarks();` to get all the bookmarks from the report embedded. Refer [Use the report bookmarks APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks#get-a-list-of-saved-report-bookmarks).

As a workaround to get the bookmarks for the report hosted in service, you can inspect the network tab to see which endpoint is getting called while hitting the `getBookmarks()` API.

You can try hitting the bookmarks API here in [Playground - Developer Sandbox](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/dev-sandbox).

Checked the network tab, and here is the internal API being called to get all the bookmarks API.

Here is the URL`https://df-msit-scus-redirect.analysis.windows.net/explore/reports/61eaf059-c9bf-46ee-ac5b-8c49e0e3e44e/modelsAndExploration`

Refer to this below snapshot where i tried hitting the above url and get the bookmarks.
[image]